# How to generate list with out for loop in python

Tags: python, map-reduce

data frame

S/N Type    Number Capacity
1   Bike      2      5
2   Tempo     1      30 
3   Truck-1   1      60
4   Truck-2   1      90

[image: Vehicle Capacities]

I would like to generate capacitylist = [5,5,30,60,90]

Is it possible to do it with out for and using map function in python. Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ndf = df.loc[ np.repeat(df.index.values, df['Number']) ]
values = ndf['Capacity'].tolist()
# [5, 5, 30, 60, 90]
```

Repeat the rows you wish you duplicate using np.repeat, and then, takes the selected column (here, `capacity`) and turn it into a list using `.tolist()`.

Comment: Thanks IMcoins, indeed it is great help, your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: @ShashankTrivedi Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer ;)